# Where am I going wrong in this derivation of second equation of kinematics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I was trying to derive the $s=ut+\frac12at^2$ equation,

where $s$=displacement;
$u$=initial velocity;
$t$=time taken;
$a$=acceleration,
on my own with some different ways;

so I took

$$v=\frac st$$

then,
$$s=vt$$

but $v=u+at$ (first equation)

so,

$$s=(u+at)t$$

$$s=ut+at^2$$

we all know this result is absurd but I am just curious to know,
where I am wrong.

Comment: $s=vt$ is only true for constant $v$, so it does *not apply* when $v=v_0+at$.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: @mikestone This should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Jonas ok from next time i will edit like that thankyou for this time.

Comment: It’s just a Taylor series with constant acceleration and zero jerk.

Comment: @gen-ℤreadytoperish Wow new way of looking at it thanks, I am ready to be perished lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @mike stone, "$s=vt$ is only true for constant $v$."

By using the $v=u+at$ equation, you're assuming that velocity changes. Therefore, $s=vt$ does not hold true.

Instead, what you could do is use the average velocity $\bar v$ on the interval $[t_0,t]$ to get, $s=\bar v t$. The average velocity over the interval $[t_0,t]$ (where $v(t_0)=u$) is $\bar v = \dfrac{2u+at}2$ (basically (u+v)/2. Your derivation would then work.